# Firefox can't work after using splinter 0.8.0

Tags: python-3.x, firefox, splinter

I have just installed the splinter 0.8.0. I intalled it like this:
 `1.Firstly, I have had installed anaconda and the corresponding spyder supports python3.7 
 2.I installed the latest selenium by using "pip install selenium" on cmd.exe
 3.I used "pip -m install splinter" to install splinter0.8.0
 4.I installed geckodriver from the github` [click here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)
 `5.I configurated the environment by getting the geckodriver.exe copied to the directory which includes fiefox.exe and get the path into the PATH of the computer
 6.To this, the splinter could open firefox but always got some exceptions..
 7*.When I then opened the firefox with mouse clicking, the firefox started with page white. And no matter what I input into the search box, nothing happened. What's more, I found that the developer tools couldn't be opened. And all these cases happened when I started firefox through desktop shortcut. Interestingly, when I started it in its directory which it's originally at, the firefox could work. But in this case when I open a new blank page, it didn't work too...`

It's so confusing!!! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be that the computer had been working long and if you shut it down completely and restart it, the Firefox may come alive. (Also it may be because of Win10's needing relax).
If that doesn't work, I recommend chromedriver.